# how to plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am struggling with the following R code for plotting;

```
set.seed(1234)
x1=rnorm(100)^2

Index=1:length(x1)
cutoff=3
plot(Index,x1,type="h")
abline(h=cutoff,lty=2)
```

Firstly, I want to plot also the index of those values that are greater than cutoff value?
And secondly, I have five plots similar to above, I am using

```
par(mfrow= c(3,2))
```

It give 3 x 2 space, but for fifth plot, I need to plot it in the center;

Comment: You have six or five plots to co-show at the end? And what do you mean by "plot the index of values above cutoff"? EDIT: See, also, if this is helpful `layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,0,5,5,0), 3, 4, byrow = T)) ; for(i in 1:5) plot(i)`

Answer (score 0):

The layout() function will be your best friend in terms of arranging the plots.

Check http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html for a good tutorial on the function.